# Get List of Data which belonging to a specific user in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

If I have this data currently in Property Table in SQL server

```
PropertyID  PropertyName   UserID
1           prop1          User1
2           prop2          User1
3           prop3          User1
4           prop4          Admin
5           prop5          Admin
```

And I only want to view by depending on the authenticated user. For Example User1 is loggedin then the items to show in the Property View must be below only, (but when the user is Admin, it will show all)

```
 PropertyID  PropertyName   UserID
    1           prop1          User1
    2           prop2          User1
    3           prop3          User1
```

This is the code snippet using the creating Controller > MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework

[image]

```
 public class PropertyController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Property
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.Property.ToListAsync());
           
        }
```

above code shows all data in the table, how can i conditionally implement to show only those belonging to a specific user?

Comment: Something like `db.Property.Where(x => x.UserID == 12345).ToListAsync()`

Comment: this helped. thanks a lot. can you also help and advise on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046211/access-identity-user-data-in-asp-net-mvc